# pointing a picture to a line of text

Tags: html, css

I have a picture of an arrow basically, and a line of text that refers to a link. I want to point that arrow graphic towards that line of text. The code I have so far is this:

```
<div>
<div id="title" style="clear:both;right:125px;">
<br><a href="http://store.incfilms.net"<font color="white" size="5" face="arial"><b>Equipment Rentals</a></b></div>

   <style="top: 210px; left: 235px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; visibility: show;">
<img src="rentals_media/click here.png" width="250" height="100"/> </style>
</div>
</div>
```

The site is incfilms.net/rentals if that makes it easier to see.   Thanks for your help

Comment: using `<font>` really??? use `css`.....

Comment: using `<style=` ? never seen that approach before.

Comment: Also, I HAVE to mention... your index page you have a VERY large image that you have scaled down via CSS (or the img tag, i didn't look). However this does not stop the browser from downloading the image in it's original size. Which is quite large and chokes the page load. Scale your images down to the size you wish them to be viewed at, and if you want to display the original image you can just make the scaled image a link to the full size.  Just a FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this HTML for the image (no style tags!):

```
<img src="rentals_media/click here.png" width="250" height="100" style="position: relative; top: -20px; left: 250px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is absolutely position that arrow and just adjust it with a top/left combination, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/VhALR/

Answer (score 0):

I think you could really simplify your HTML markup and css here, like this

```
<a href="#" title="Click Here">Click Here</a>
<img src="http://incfilms.net/rentals/rentals_media/click%20here.png" />
```

**CSS**

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    height:103px;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-top:2px;
}
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/VhALR/1/